# How To Validate HTTP Reports from User Agents

Tags: http, http-headers

With the new HTTP reporting headers being developed and refined, it seems more important than ever to be able to tell/validate where the reports are coming from.

For example, someone attempting to "hack" the site can very easily flood the reporting endpoint with false reports, drowning out the details of what they're attempting.  It's also a vector for a DDOS attack.

Is there some mechanism for doing this aside from obfuscation?

Do the User Agents sign their reports?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

I took a quick glance through the standard draft for the `Report-To` header, but it doesn't seem to touch on it.

One thought on application-level mitigation: record the IPs of all clients that are connected and authenticated and only accept reports from IPs that are whitelisted in this way.  This assumes that the browser sends its reports direct from the client machine (I believe this is the case, but can anyone confirm?).